# How to make a script with commands requiring mix of sudo & sudo -u username permissions?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, permissions

I want to make a script that runs some commands with sudo permission & some commmands with sudo -u username permission.

Currently,
I run script using sudo permission, which executes each command in the script with sudo permission. But what I want to do is run some commands with normal user permissions. For example: If I create a directory then I don't want to be created by super-user. Otherwise it becomes difficult to delete it from file manager until I open file manager in root mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# this declares that current user is a sudoer
sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/$USER <<END
END

# write the content of your script here
sudo npm install hexo-cli -g
mkdir Untitled
sudo apt-get install python

# then to remove the sudo access from the current user
sudo /bin/rm /etc/sudoers.d/$USER
sudo -k
```

Comment: Where in the `sudo` documentation does it say that simply creating a file named after a user makes them a `sudoer`? As far as I can tell, adding an empty file here would do nothing. Second, you have use to sudo run the command, so there's a catch-22. How you can use `sudo` to add a user as a `sudoer` since the user can't run the `sudo` command to perform the action?

Answer (score 0):

You either run a script as a user, and put some `sudo` command in it, or you run the script with `sudo`, and use `su` to run specific commands within the script as a certain user.